# How to generate matplotlib figures inside a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

Hello I have a piece of code which reads an excel data file, does some stuff to it and then plots a figure. Now i want to be able to plot many excel data files at the same time and each should be plotted to its own figure.

example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import MultiCursor
import matplotlib.pylab as pl

Files_to_read = np.array([r"C:\file1",r"C:\file2"])
for ii in range(len(Files_to_read)):
   df=pd.read_excel(Files_to_read[ii])
#do a lot of stuff to "df"
   fig, ((ax1,ax2),(ax3,ax4)) = plt.subplots(2,2,sharex=True)
   fig.suptitle('some name')
   p1 = ax1.plot(df["some vector"], df["some vector"])
   p2 = ax2.plot(df["some vector"], df["some vector"])
   p3 = ax3.plot(df["some vector"], df["some vector"])
   p4 = ax4.plot(df["some vector"], df["some vector"])
   multi = MultiCursor(fig.canvas, (ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4), color='r', lw=1)
   plt.show()
```

Doing it like this generates 1 figure with the data of the first file and then overwrites the same figure with the data of the second file, how can I change it to generate a new figure on each pass through the for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your call to `plt.show()` so that it occurs after the for loop has been complete. All created figures should be visualized at once.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, i want to view all the figures at the same time. How would i reconstruct the axis objects? I would need to change the line: `fig, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplots(2, 2, sharex=True)` somehow right?

Comment: I had a realization, try running that for-loop as you have it, but call `plt.show()` outside of the for-loops scope (end of program, I mean). That might let you view them all at the same time. I believe a new call to "subplots" creates a new figure and keeps the old one. I always have trouble with matplotlib's "imperative" style.

Comment: that was it, thanks a lot! moving plt.show() outside the for loop makes all figures show when the program finishes. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome! In case you're interested in moving away from mpl, I would suggest looking into plotly. It's a great plotting framework, and 3-dimensional plots work much smoother than mpl.